# Can Java run two statements at one time

Tags: java

When I run this code it works perfectly. But it made me think that after the program executed `timer.start()` function how is it still execute the `actionPerformed()` method until I enter "end" in the input. It has passed the statement `timer.start()` and somehow still it executes it after the time has passed. Is this running two statements together or am I missing some points ?

```
var listner= new TimePrinter();
Timer timer=new Timer(10000,listner);
timer.start();
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
String q=scanner.nextLine();
while(!q.equals("end")){
  System.out.println(" ");
  q=scanner.nextLine();
}

class TimePrinter implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String q=Instant.ofEpochMilli(event.getWhen()).toString();
    System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + event.toString()+" "+event.getWhen());
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
  }
}
```

Comment: Notes that you're using a Swing timer, by the looks of it. All timer listeners will execute on the UI thread, but maybe your other code is running on a different thread - it's hard to tell from the incomplete sample code. If you're new to threads, you should probably read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java can run multiple set of instructions in a sort of light-weight processes (called Threads) in parallel. A thread scheduler schedules all of them over the different processor cores of your system. Modern systems can run multiple of them in parallel.

That's also why the user interface is not freezing when downloading data at the same time. The code to handle the UI updates or events is still processed when doing another background task.

Comment: I would strongly advise not referring to threads as processes, given that that's a different concept. Additionally, the aspect of running on different cores isn't necessary for this to work - the UI wouldn't freeze even if the OP had just one core.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I tried to explain it somehow simple.

Comment: Sure, but there's a cost to simplifying things in a way that introduces further confusion. (As an example, I see that a lot in people trying to simplify method parameter handling in Java by claiming that arguments are "passed by reference" when what they mean is that arguments are passed by value, but those values might be references.) Explaining something simply without *over*-simplifying is certainly tricky, but important.

Comment: Sir can you explain that when main method reaches to the end do all threads stop?

Comment: @JonSkeet Your comment *Explaining something simply without over-simplifying is certainly tricky, but important.*  is the key point I think. That should be our goal when helping people

Comment: Right. So are you going to edit the answer to address the points I raised?

Answer (score 1):

Its running them "together" because its running them in separate threads from the main program. Hope this answers your question.

Check out multi-threading in java.

Comment: Yes it answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is a multi-threading language. It can run two statement at the same time using two different threads. When you use graphical user interfaces to your programs java uses separate threads for the GUI and for the back-end program to do the tasks associated with the GUI inputs. That's why the user interface doesn't freeze when you press a button in  the interface.